# reposition text field above keyboard on tableview when tap (similar to whatsapp)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I need to know what are the steps in order.To create a table view controller and add a View that holds inside a text field and a Button, that would reposition itself on Y axis when the keyboard appears similar to whatsapps messaging system. and reverses it's position when user gestures on the tableview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the UItableViewController that takes all the view space. You should instead use a UIViewController and add a UITableview on it. Then you are able to controll the size of the UITableView and you can have space to add the textfield under it.